# overloading explicit CAST operator

Tags: c#, .net, casting, proxy, operator-overloading

I have this piece of code:

```
public class Leg : ProxiestChild
{
    public virtual Name { get; set; }
}
```

the problem is:

```
var leg = new Leg(); // leg is not Leg, instead ProxiedLeg

var trueleg = (Leg)leg; // exception leg is a ProxiedLeg
```

i need something like this

```
public class ProxiestChild
{
    // some method that overloads explicit CAST
    // where receiving the proxied object i returns the unproxied object
    // to be casted
}
```

Comment: This might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Your code is not clear, because it *does* create an instance of `Leg`. Can you show a short but complete program which actually demonstrates the problem - and give us more context about why you want to do this?

Comment: @Adam Houldsworth is just what i needed (pretty cool link), thanks, can you please let your answer to rate it?

Comment: @manuellt I've created the answer, although I do agree with Jon's comments, the OP code is a little misleading.

Comment: thanks, i posted another question based on this one "more clear" here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833227/overloading-explicit-cast-operator-with-user-defined-interface-parameter

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can implement custom type casting using the conversion operators `implicit` or `explicit`.

Conversion operators can be explicit or implicit. Implicit conversion operators are easier to use, but explicit operators are useful when you want users of the operator to be aware that a conversion is taking place. This topic demonstrates both types.

### Example

This is an example of an explicit conversion operator. This operator converts from the type [Byte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyb1w04y(v=vs.100)) to a value type called Digit. Because not all bytes can be converted to a digit, the conversion is explicit, meaning that a cast must be used, as shown in the Main method.

```
struct Digit
{
    byte value;

    public Digit(byte value)  //constructor
    {
        if (value > 9)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException();
        }
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static explicit operator Digit(byte b)  // explicit byte to digit conversion operator
    {
        Digit d = new Digit(b);  // explicit conversion

        System.Console.WriteLine("Conversion occurred.");
        return d;
    }
}

class TestExplicitConversion
{
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            byte b = 3;
            Digit d = (Digit)b;  // explicit conversion
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
        }
    }
}
// Output: Conversion occurred.
```

This example demonstrates an implicit conversion operator by defining a conversion operator that undoes what the previous example did: it converts from a value class called Digit to the integral [Byte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyb1w04y(v=vs.100)) type. Because any digit can be converted to a [Byte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyb1w04y(v=vs.100)), there's no need to force users to be explicit about the conversion.

```
struct Digit
{
    byte value;

    public Digit(byte value)  //constructor
    {
        if (value > 9)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException();
        }
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator byte(Digit d)  // implicit digit to byte conversion operator
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("conversion occurred");
        return d.value;  // implicit conversion
    }
}

class TestImplicitConversion
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Digit d = new Digit(3);
        byte b = d;  // implicit conversion -- no cast needed
    }
}
// Output: Conversion occurred.
```

from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a(v=VS.100).aspx

Do be careful with this, for readability it can often be confusing to see one type magically cast to another - people don't always first think that there are conversion operators in play.