# overloading explicit CAST operator with user-defined interface parameter

Tags: c#, nhibernate, casting, proxy, overloading

At these given classes

```
[ActiveRecord]
public class BaseMoo : ActiveRecordBase

[ActiveRecord]
public class Foo : BaseMoo { }
```

somewhere in the code i do

```
var fooObj = new Foo();
// do something with fooObj
BaseMoo obj = fooObj;
```

here i try to cast

```
var newFooObj = (Foo)obj; // and goes well
```

if i changes the classes to this:

```
[ActiveRecord(Lazy=true)]
public class BaseMoo : ActiveRecordBase

[ActiveRecord(Lazy=true)]
public class Foo : BaseMoo { }
```

making it Lazyest at these lines:

```
var fooObj = new Foo();
// do something with fooObj
BaseMoo obj = fooObj;
```

the AR creates non a Foo instance instead a BaseMooProxy object

```
var newFooObj = (Foo)obj; // this throws an invalidcast exception
```

As sugested by @Adam Houldsworth in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792282/overloading-explicit-cast-operator)

I overloads the Foo explicit operator in this way

```
public static explicit operator Foo(NHibernate.Proxy.INHibernateProxy nhProxy)
{
    var resultObj = (Foo)nhProxy.InSomeWayIGetTheOriginalObject(); // InSomeWayIGetTheOriginalObject() is not a real method, only for simplify
    return resultObj;
}
```

but i get an error in the operator overload parameter

```
NHibernate.Proxy.INHibernateProxy nhProxy

user-defined conversion from interface
```

QUESTION:

1. how can i do to explicit convert from BaseMooProxy (NHibernate.Proxy.INHibernateProxy) to Foo?
2. As know it's not possible to overloads the "is" operator, is there a way to do work the "obj is Foo" ?

As the consumer application is 3th part customer It's not possible to changes the way how the application casts the classes objects.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you want to define this explicit cast operator? in BaseMoo?

Comment: @manuellt Just a note, the conversion operators don't work on interfaces so that is a non-starter. You will need to identify the type that implements the interface and cast from that, but chances are good you can't as this is all built at runtime.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth into the Foo class, thanx

Comment: @Adam Houlddsworth giving as parameter the class type that implements the interface (BaseMoo because BaseMoo is proxied as BaseMooProxy) i get the error "Conversion from base class", thanx.