# Cast one class object to other class object

Tags: c#

I have two classes A and B and I want to cast an instance of A to B. What's the best way?
How Can I make a utility class to perform this task?

```
public class A
{}
public class B
{}
```

Comment: You'll have to implement your own conversion to go from one class to the other.

Comment: The classes, as you have defined in your question, cannot be cast to one another. C# is a strongly-typed language so you can do such a casting. Casting can only be performed up and down the line of inheritance (base classes or interfaces).

Comment: The two types as described in your question are completely unrelated, so they cannot be cast one to the other. As Tim says, you _can_ provide a conversion which would copy or otherwise initialize an instance of one type based on the other.

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792282/overloading-explicit-cast-operator)

Comment: i mean to say to change object or map to other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good place to start is by reviewing the MSDN documentation on [Casting and Type Conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx).

As there's no direct relationship between the two classes, you'll need to write a [Conversion Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09479473.aspx). For example:

```
public class A
{
    public int AValue { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int BValue { get; set; }

    public static explicit operator B(A instanceOfA)
    {
        return new B { BValue = instanceOfA.AValue };
    }
}
```

You could then write:

```
A instanceOfA = new A { AValue = 7 };
B instanceOfB = (B)instanceOfA;

// Will output "7"
Console.WriteLine(instanceOfB.BValue);
```

The documentation I've derived this example from is on MSDN, [Using Conversion Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx).

If there was a direct relationship between the two classes, for example `B` derives from `A`, for example:

```
public class A
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class B : A
{
    public string OtherValueSpecificToB { get; set; }
}
```

You wouldn't then need any extra code if you wanted to cast from B to A:

```
B instanceOfB = new B { OtherValueSpecificToB = "b", Value = 3 };
A instanceOfBCastToA = (A)instanceOfB;

// Will output "3";
Console.WriteLine(instanceOfBCastToA.Value);
// Will not compile as when being treated as an "A" there is no "OtherValueSpecificToB" property
Console.WriteLine(instanceOfBCastToA.OtherValueSpecificToB);
```