# Typecast from subclass1 to parent class to subclass2, is this possible?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, casting, telerik

I'm working with a C# WPF application, which uses a kind of inheritance:

`Main_Class` has two subclasses, `Sub_Class1` and `Sub_Class2`.

In my application, I work with objects of `Sub_Class1`.
Another application works with objects of `Sub_Class2`.

I have the impression that the following is happening:

My application creates an object of `Sub_Class1` and store it in DB (due to Telerik technology, the `voa_class` gets filled in as `Sub_Class1`).
The other application uses objects of type `Main_Class` and modifies them in database.
My application captures the database modifications and finds that an object, derived from `Main_Class` has been modified. In my application, I do:

```
((Sub_Class1)Db_Object)...
```

But, as the object is of type `Sub_Class1`, the typecast goes into an exception.

I would like to handle this in the following way (I don't care about losing `Sub_Class2` information):

```
((Sub_Class1) (Main_Class) Db_Object)...
```

In other words: first typecast to the main class, and only then to the subclass, used in my application.

Can this work? (The application is currently installed at a customer site, so it's not easy to just do some "trial-and-error")

**Edit after first comments**
Apparently, my simple approach does not work. What about this:

```
Main_Class Main_Object = Db_Object;
Sub_Class1 Sub_Object1 = (Sub_Class1) Main_Object;
```

### **Edit after some thoughts: general O.O. reflection**

In fact, it all comes down to this (very general):

```
class Sub_Class : Main_Class { ... }
...
Sub_Class Sub_Object = ...;

Main_Class Main_Object = Sub_Object;              // or:
Main_Class Main_Object = (Main_Class) Sub_Object;
```

In both cases, `Main_Object` won't be a `Main_Class`, but a `Sub_Class` object.
Although this is handy in a lot of cases (it's even a basic feature for quite some O.O. implementations), it might be hindering (like in my case). It's quite a pity that no simple solution/workaround exists for this particular case.

Comment: Unless Sub_Class2 inherits from Sub_Class1, then no, this isn't possible. Consider the base class `Animal` has two derived classes: `Dog` and `Cat`. `Dog` has a `.Bark();` method and `Cat` has a `.Meow();` method. With your proposal, `Cat myCat = (Cat)(Animal)dogInstance;` should be possible, but then `myCat.Meow():` wouldn't work because you really have a `Dog`. If you just want to keep the common data, you could look at using something like AutoMapper.

Comment: No. Casting is a compile time thing, and `Sub_Class1` and `Sub_Class2` are unrelated. What you need is a conversion, and there are a number of ways to do that.

Comment: `(Sub_Class1) Main_Object;` will fail if `Db_Object` isn't a `Sub_Class1`. You say you can't do trial and error because the application is installed at a customer site. I don't see why not. You can mock up a trivial example in a new application easily.

Comment: [Like this](https://rextester.com/FPO1625).

Comment: Is there a way to do what I'm looking for (as I mentioned, I don't care about losing `Sub_Class1` related information)?

Comment: Yes, you can write code where you pass a Sub_Class2 and it creates a new Sub_Class1 for you. Or you can use a tool like AutoMapper if you want to avoid writing mapping code.

Comment: You could also provide that mapping code as a cast operator (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792282/overloading-explicit-cast-operator)) so that you could then use it like `Sub_Class1 Sub_Object1 = (Sub_Class1)Db_Object;`.